# TypeError in vue project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, frontend

[image]
[image]

hello everyone , I changed the type of these two values inside the pinia library, and I tried to make these two values accessible from the cache, and vscode reported an error saying that the first line of the first image did not have an overload that matched this call.The error is as following:

```
There are no overloads that match this call
  第 1 个重载(共 3 个)，“(id: "user", options: Omit<DefineStoreOptions<"user", UserState, _GettersTree<UserState>, { setInfo(user: { id: number; email: string; is_active: boolean; is_superuser: boolean; ... 6 more ...; setting: { ...; }; }): void; ... 4 more ...; logout(): Promise<...>; }>, "id">): StoreDefinition<...>”，出现以下错误。
    不能将类型“(state: UserState) => { id: number; email: string; is_active: boolean; is_superuser: boolean; is_verified: boolean; username: string; nickname: string; last_active_time?: string | undefined; create_time: string; avatar?: string | undefined; setting: { ...; }; } | null”分配给类型“(() => any) | ((state: { user: { id: number; email: string; is_active: boolean; is_superuser: boolean; is_verified: boolean; username: string; nickname: string; last_active_time?: string | undefined; create_time: string; avatar?: string | undefined; setting: { ...; }; } | null; savedUsername: string; savedPassword: ...”。
      不能将类型“(state: UserState) => { id: number; email: string; is_active: boolean; is_superuser: boolean; is_verified: boolean; username: string; nickname: string; last_active_time?: string | undefined; create_time: string; avatar?: string | undefined; setting: { ...; }; } | null”分配给类型“() => any”。
        Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.
  第 2 个重载(共 3 个)，“(id: "user", storeSetup: () => unknown, options?: DefineSetupStoreOptions<"user", _UnwrapAll<Pick<unknown, never>>, Pick<unknown, never>, Pick<unknown, never>> | undefined): StoreDefinition<...>”，出现以下错误。
    类型“{ state: () => UserState; getters: { userInfo(state: UserState): { id: number; email: string; is_active: boolean; is_superuser: boolean; is_verified: boolean; username: string; ... 4 more ...; setting: { ...; }; } | null; }; actions: { ...; }; }”的参数不能赋给类型“() => unknown”的参数。
      Object literals can only specify known properties, and "state" is not of type "() => unknown".
```

If you want to read the whole code, you can access the PR https://github.com/moeakwak/chatgpt-web-share/pull/235

I mimick the original author and write the code,but his code is correct and my code is error.Although the function is normal,the code review don't pass.